# Adding/removing perms to discord role Discord.net

Tags: c#, discord.net

Hello recently i wanted to make a command that can modify a role perms.

For examlple:
`prefix.modrole @role add/remove ban kick mute`
So if i look into the server roles i should see that this specific role has been added/removed those perms.
Here is what i tryied:

```
switch(perms){
case "ban":
   var currentPerms=role.Permissions;
   currentPerms.Modify(banMembers:true);
try{
      await role.ModifyAsync(rp=>rp.Permissions=currentPerms);
   }catch(Exception e)
   {
      //handeling error code here
   }
.
.
```

But when i look it up in server that role perms aren't changed. And it doesnt give me any exception.
The bot and user have permission to manage roles.

EDIT:
Tryied to do this:

```
 await role.ModifyAsync(rp=>rp.Permissions=rp.Permissions.Modify(banMembers:true));
```

But if there are more than 1 perm
For example:
`prefix.command @role ban mute admin`
Only the last perm is added to the @role.

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned, you can use the following change role permissions:

```cs
await role.ModifyAsync(rp=>rp.Permissions=rp.Permissions.Modify(banMembers:true));
```

It's pretty simple to do that for multiple permissions:

```cs
await role.ModifyAsync(rp => rp.Permissions = rp.Permissions.Modify(banMembers: true, kickMembers: true));
```

Simply add as many permissions as you need, separated by commas.